# How to come out from a nodejs code execution with a value from db?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am a php programmer recently I have startled using nodejs in-order to get a project done which is unfortunately may be fortunately  using dynamo db as well so here I am coming out with a problem i know it might be basic might be as stupid as it is

The code which is excecuting is here

```
  if (typeof(req.body.question) == 'object') {
          quest = req.body.question;
        }
        if (typeof(req.body.question) == 'string') {
          quest = req.body.question;
        }else{
          questionsq = {
            'ConsistentRead': true,
            TableName : 'testquestions',
            KeyConditionExpression: "testid = :testid",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":testid":{'S':'f3b21bf0-d6b9-11e8-bdf1-f7fcc44e7f9c'} }
          };
          vulog.info('Question is not settled so querying',questionsq);
          dynamodb.query(questionsq, function(err,quest){
              vulog.info('The data:',JSON.stringify(quest));
              if(err || !quest ){
                  vulog.error('Query went wrong',err);
              }else{
                vulog.info('Query went fine',JSON.stringify(quest));
                //return quest;
              }
          });
        }
```

After this i am expecting this code to work.

```
var originalQuestions = [];
vulog.debug('--------------------');
if (!quest || quest.length == 0) {
  vulog.warn('Questions not entered');
  errstr += '\nAt least one interview question must be entered';
} else {
 //Goes on
```

At present i am getting this in at terminal and it get stucked there and there is no further execution.

```
Query went fine {"Items":[{//Datas}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

What i want is this i want the first portion of the code to execute and come out with the value of quest then continue code execution. How can i do that Right now it is excecuting and get stuck there 
vulog.info('Query went fine',JSON.stringify(quest)); No further executions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Async/Await Approach:

```js
async function() {
  ........
  var quest = await queryQuestion();
  var originalQuestions = [];
  vulog.debug('--------------------');
  if (!quest || quest.length == 0) {
    vulog.warn('Questions not entered');
    errstr += '\nAt least one interview question must be entered';
  } else {
    //Goes on
  }
}
```

---

Original Answer:

You can wrap the first logic in a function and return a Promise which in turn will `resolve` to `quest` or `reject` with `error`

```js
function queryQuestion() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (typeof(req.body.question) == 'object' || typeof(req.body.question) == 'string') {
        quest = req.body.question;
       resolve(quest);
    } else {
        questionsq = {
            'ConsistentRead': true,
            TableName: 'testquestions',
            KeyConditionExpression: "testid = :testid",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":testid": {
                    'S': 'f3b21bf0-d6b9-11e8-bdf1-f7fcc44e7f9c'
                }
            }
        };
        vulog.info('Question is not settled so querying', questionsq);
        dynamodb.query(questionsq, function(err, quest) {
            vulog.info('The data:', JSON.stringify(quest));
            if (err || !quest) {
                vulog.error('Query went wrong', err);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                vulog.info('Query went fine', JSON.stringify(quest));
                //return quest;
                resolve(quest);
            }
        });
    }
})
}
```

And then call this function

```js
queryQuestion().then(function(quest){
  var originalQuestions = [];
  vulog.debug('--------------------');
  if (!quest || quest.length == 0) {
    vulog.warn('Questions not entered');
    errstr += '\nAt least one interview question must be entered';
  } else {
    //Goes on
  }
}, function(error){
  // Handle errors
})
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: if (typeof(req.body.question) == 'object') {
          quest = req.body.question;
        }
        if (typeof(req.body.question) == 'string') {
          quest = req.body.question;
        }else{ quest = result} Is there a way to do somthing like this?

Comment: Also with the above code i am getting Promise { <pending> } in terminal

Comment: I've updated the code above. give it a try. change the if-else as per your needs. make sure the function calls either `resolve` or `reject` in every possible scenario

Comment: How can i get the value inside quest variable? The second part which you have showed i didn't understood. Properly.

Comment: This is how i am calling the function right now quest = queryQuestion();

Comment: it's an async function (since we're returning a promise). So `quest = queryQuestion()` will not work.

`queryQuestion().then(function(quest){
  // Handle success response
}, function(error){
  // Handle errors
})`

you get the `quest` value inside the first function inside `then()`

You can read more about Promise here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Then how can i get the value inside quest?

Comment: I've updated the original answer. Please check the original answer and see if it makes any sense now.
You need to understand how promises work in javascript to understand this. I've attached link in my last comment

Comment: No! No, i cant use it in that way  // Goes on is strange and big i just want the result inside quest and execute synchronously .

Comment: If i am getting the value inside quest then i am ok.

Comment: See this part of code, queryQuestion().then(function(quest){
          // Handle success response
          vulog.info('The quest:',quest);
        }, function(error){
          // Handle errors
          vulog.info('There is an error',error);
        }) This excecute and shows this in terminal The quest: { Items: } then it stuck no flow How can i do that I dont want to put the second part of logic after the queryQuestion().then(function(quest){ just exit from this and continue this is what exactly without promise also doing

Comment: It's async code. it cannot execute synchronously. Your best bet would be async/await which makes it look like synchronous. 

that part where second part of your logic is defined should be declared as async function
`async function(){
   ........
var quest = await queryQuestion();
  var originalQuestions = [];
vulog.debug('--------------------');
if (!quest || quest.length == 0) {
  vulog.warn('Questions not entered');
  errstr += '\nAt least one interview question must be entered';
} else {
 //Goes on
}
}`

Comment: How can i do that that is what my question is?